# Trackment protection code

Tags: javascript, html

I have signed up Trackment, added my website. The given code for my website is like;

```
<script src="http://trackment.com/?p=**code**"></script>
```

In their description, I need to add on my page, just after body tag. The problem is that my designer havent add the body tag in the page, since its a flash website.

I have added their code after my html tag, it works fine, however I suspect if its working 100% correctly.

My question is, is it must to add the javascript code in between body tags or its just a suggestion ? Note: javascript and jquery are included in my web page.

Comment: Kudos to your designer...

Comment: If it works now, then what's the problem? But I'm confused here: all webpages, even Flash-based ones, have (or should have) a `<body>` element. It seems like the structure of your pages is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<script/>` tag is legal in both the `<head/>` and `<body/>` sections.  Technically your site is invalid HTML as the [`<html/>` tag's content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element) requires one `<head/>` followed by one `<body/>` section.  However most browsers will bend over backward to fix crappy HTML and so it's assuming an implicit `<body/>` tag following an empty `<head/>` tag.

TL;DR you're fine putting it right after `<html/>` but it's not guaranteed to work on 100% of browsers.  But nothing on the web is either.